# Shortcut for opening applications stack on dock bar

Tags: keyboard, dock, applications

Is there any keyboard shortcut to open applications stack on dock bar?

The idea is I want to be able to open any app without using mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

..selects an item of the dock. You can navigate using the **arrow keys**. The selected item is the one that will be selected *first* the next time you use this shortcut.

Once you've selected the Applications folder, the shortcut becomes for the next time:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>↩</kbd>

[image]

BTW:
You can also use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to access menubar items.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should try [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) or [QuickSilver](http://qsapp.com/). Both of them give you the ability to open any applications quickly, not just the applications on dock.

[image: Alfred Screenshot]

Play around with them and I am sure you will find your workflow on Mac more efficient.

Comment: And it's so much faster than spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way (that I can think of) to open the Applications folder is the following:

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. (This is the fastest way to open a new Finder window from within any application.)

Then, browse to the Applications folder by hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

> The idea is I want to be able to open any app without using mouse.

I have <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> mapped to Spotlight, so I can just use that keyboard shortcut, then start typing the name of an app, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and that’s it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Spotlight? It's fast and doesn't require any other software installed. By default it has a shortcut <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> (you can set this shortcut in System Preferences).

Spotlight quickly finds the application (or file) as you type.

[image: Spotlight Search for Application]

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick for switching application windows including the minimised ones in MAC OS X.

After choosing the app by pressing CMD + tab, hold press option key and release other keys. Minimized window will be opened.

[Source](http://www.macworld.com/article/1152366/commandtabminimizedwindows.html)

Comment: OP is referring to the Applications **stack** in the Dock, not a minimised application…